# My pictures wont show when I build and run uicollection view

Tags: swift, layout, uicollectionview, pinterest

```
import UIKit



class HomePageCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet private weak var containerView: UIView!
  
    @IBOutlet weak var photos: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var songname: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var songmaker: UILabel!
    
    //@IBOutlet weak var pfppic: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var viewcount: UILabel!
    

    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        containerView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        
    }
    
    var photo: Photo? {
        didSet {
            if let photo = photo {
                photos.image = photo.image
                songname.text = photo.name
                songmaker.text = photo.makername
                viewcount.text = photo.likecount
        
     
                
            }
        }
    }
    
   override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        
        self.photos.image = nil
    }
    
        
    
}

import UIKit

protocol PinterestLayoutDelegate: AnyObject {
    func collectionView(
        _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
        heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
}

class PinterestLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    
    // 1
    weak var delegate: PinterestLayoutDelegate?
    
    // 2
    private let numberOfColumns = 2
    private let cellPadding: CGFloat = 6
    
    // 3
    private var cache: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []
    
    // 4
    private var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    private var contentWidth: CGFloat {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return 0
        }
        let insets = collectionView.contentInset
        return collectionView.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
    }
    
    // 5
    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
    }
    
    override func prepare() {
        // 1
        guard
            cache.isEmpty,
            let collectionView = collectionView
            else {
                return
        }
        // 2
        let columnWidth = contentWidth / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
        var xOffset: [CGFloat] = []
        for column in 0..<numberOfColumns {
            xOffset.append(CGFloat(column) * columnWidth)
        }
        var column = 0
        var yOffset: [CGFloat] = .init(repeating: 0, count: numberOfColumns)
        
        // 3
        for item in 0..<collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
            
            // 4
            let photoHeight = delegate?.collectionView(
                collectionView,
                heightForPhotoAtIndexPath: indexPath) ?? 180
            let height = cellPadding * 2 + photoHeight
            let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[column],
                               y: yOffset[column],
                               width: columnWidth,
                               height: height)
            let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: cellPadding, dy: cellPadding)
            
            // 5
            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
            attributes.frame = insetFrame
            cache.append(attributes)
            
            // 6
            contentHeight = max(contentHeight, frame.maxY)
            yOffset[column] = yOffset[column] + height
            
            column = column < (numberOfColumns - 1) ? (column + 1) : 0
        }
    }
    
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect)
        -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
            var visibleLayoutAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []
            
            // Loop through the cache and look for items in the rect
            for attributes in cache {
                if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
                    visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
                }
            }
            return visibleLayoutAttributes
    }
    
    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath)
        -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
            return cache[indexPath.item]
    }
    
}

extension HomePageViewController: PinterestLayoutDelegate {
    func collectionView(
        _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
        heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return photos[indexPath.item].image.size.height
    }
}

import UIKit

struct Photo {
   
    var image: UIImage
    var name: String
    var makername: String
    var likecount: String
  
    
    init(image: UIImage, name: String, makername: String, likecount: String) {
        
        self.image = image
        self.name = name
        self.makername = makername
        self.likecount = likecount
     
    
    }
    
    init?(dictionary: [String: String]) {
        guard
            let name = dictionary["Name"],
            let makername = dictionary["Makername"],
            let photo = dictionary["Photo"],
            let likecount = dictionary["Likecount"],
            let image = UIImage(named: photo)
            else {
                return nil
        }
        self.init(image: image, name: name, makername: makername, likecount: likecount)
    }
    
    static func allPhotos() -> [Photo] {
        var photos: [Photo] = []
        guard
            let URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Photos", withExtension: "plist"),
            let photosFromPlist = NSArray(contentsOf: URL) as? [[String:String]]
            else {
                return photos
        }
        for dictionary in photosFromPlist {
            if let photo = Photo(dictionary: dictionary) {
                photos.append(photo)
            }
        }
        return photos
    }
}

import UIKit


final class HomePageViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    // MARK: - Properties

    var photos = Photo.allPhotos()
    
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? PinterestLayout {
            layout.delegate = self
            
            
        }
        
        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.delegate = self

        let iconImage = UIImage(named: "name")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: iconImage)
        self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
    }

    
    private let sectionInsets2 = UIEdgeInsets(
        top: 50.0,
        left: 20.0,
        bottom: 50.0,
        right: 20.0)
    
   
    private let itemsPerRow: CGFloat = 1
    private let itemsPerRow1: CGFloat = 1
    private let itemsPerRow2: CGFloat = 2
    // MARK: - Private

    
    
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return 1
        } else if section == 1 {
            return 1
        } else {
            return photos.count
        }
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomePageHeaderCell", for: indexPath) as! HomePageHeaderCell
          
            
            return cell
            
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomePageProfileBar", for: indexPath) as! HomePageProfileBar
          
     
            return cell
            
            
        } else if indexPath.section == 2 {
            
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomePageCell", for: indexPath) as! HomePageCell
            
            cell.photo = photos[indexPath.item]
            //cell.pfppic.image = UIImage(named: "pfppic")
            //cell.pfppic.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0

         
        
            return cell
        }
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

    
}


extension HomePageViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    // 1
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        // 2H
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            
            let paddingSpace = 0 * (itemsPerRow + 1)
            let availableWidth = view.frame.width - paddingSpace
            let widthPerItem = availableWidth / itemsPerRow
        
            return CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: 50)
            
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            
            let paddingSpace1 = 0 * (itemsPerRow1 + 1)
            let availableWidth1 = view.frame.width - paddingSpace1
            let widthPerItem1 = availableWidth1 / itemsPerRow1
            
            return CGSize(width: widthPerItem1, height: 100)
        } else {
            
            let paddingSpace2 = sectionInsets2.left * (itemsPerRow2 + 1)
            let availableWidth2 = view.frame.width - paddingSpace2
            let widthPerItem2 = availableWidth2 / itemsPerRow2
            
            return CGSize(width: widthPerItem2, height: widthPerItem2)
        }
       
    }
    
    // 3
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return sectionInsets2
    }
    
    // 4
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return sectionInsets2.left
    }
}
```

I have the array built and I don't know why any pictures won't show

Comment: You posted over 340 lines of code. You need to provide a better explanation of your code and how it's failing to meet your need than "My pictures wont show when I build and run uicollection view" and "I have the array built and I don't know why any pictures won't show". Tell us how your code is supposed to work. Tell us what array you built. Tell us what you've tried in order to debug it. If you want us to debug that much code, upload your project to Github and provide a link so we can download and try it ourselves.

Comment: Are you sure you have the images with the correct names in your asset catalog?

Comment: It looks like your view controller has a function `allPhotos()` that is supposed to load a plist describing your photos, and then load the images named in that plist. Have you stepped through that code to see if the plist is loaded successfully? Have you checked to see if the images have been loaded? Have you looked at your photos array once the function returns to make sure it is populated correctly?